# In Clash of Clans, is it possible to attack another member of your clan in a normal raid?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Something that I've been curious about for a while. I know the algorithm puts you against players with similar trophy levels, but could you, in theory, attack another member of your clan?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to attack fellow clan members. There are regulations within the game to prevent it.

Comment: Any proof? Even today, this is still being speculated.

Comment: No proof other than this.
http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/688145-You-can-attack-other-clan-members?p=4674730&viewfull=1#post4674730

Comment: Er.. That's not a Normal raid. The post was talking about a Revenge raid. (Note that when he was attacked, that person wasn't in the same clan as him)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot attack fellow clan members even if you wanted to. Believe me, I've tried. :D

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. I think there are much more conditions to raid than just same trophy level

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but it is less than a 0.1% chance that you will...
You'd both have to have about the same amount of trophies and be in the same league.

---

I thought it'd be cool if Supercell let you try out a army by attacking a Clan Member but not taking any loot or lose/win any trophies... It'd be like if you were training...

---

This is the simplest way to attack someone in the same clan as you...

If you were raided by a player and you invited them to join your clan and they accepted.  You could still attack their base by using the Revenge option in your Defense Log.